# Checking if checkbox is checked or not via macro

Tags: vba

I have check box in my xls sheet. How can i find if these are checked or not via macro.
I have created these checkbox manually from Forrm Controller.

Thanks,
Mona

Answer (score 6):

```
if CheckBox1.Value = true then
    'your code
end if
```